# Best resources for learning PyGame?

Tags: python, pygame

Just curious if anyone knows of good sites for learning and understanding PyGame.
I've programmed a bunch in Python, so I'm well-equipped with that. Just curious if anyone knows a good site or more for learning PyGame.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have [several Pygame bookmarks](http://delicious.com/bcorfman/pygame) on my delicious page that I think are worth a look. The links cover both tutorials and libraries to make your Pygame development easier. It would also be worth looking at a good, complete game written with Pygame to get an idea of how it should be structured. There are plenty of excellent ones on [Ian Mallett's page](http://geometrian.com/programming/projects/index.php), for instance. Good luck on your game writing!

Comment: The three links are all broken.

Comment: Try again. The first one is still valid, I updated the second and deleted the third since it no longer exists.

Comment: links are not working

Comment: I recently switched over to Diigo for bookmarking since delicious has become a wasteland. [See if you can access things here.](https://www.diigo.com/user/bcorfman1?query=%23pygame)

Answer (score 3):

Eli Bendersky writes well and has [written a tutorial](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/12/13/writing-a-game-in-python-with-pygame-part-i/) "not for beginners". It's certainly worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

I really liked this tutorial: http://rene.f0o.com/mywiki/PythonGameProgramming. I found that it was an excellent way to get started with learning the basics of the library itself.

The whole of http://pygame.org is brilliant if you haven't found that already. The documentation section is great, as is the tutorial section.

Comment: I'll second pygame.org - if you are familiar with programming and reading documentation and familiar with the python object model, then reading the docs/refs at pygame.org is probably about as much as you need, with perhaps a slight introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Invent Your Own Computer Games with Python -ebook has some nice PyGame chapters.

http://inventwithpython.com/

Answer (score 0):

Others pointed to good tutorials so I rather give an advice. Start to download some games listed on pygame.org and learn, examine their sources. Play around them, make changes and see how they behave. This is the best way to get practice.
I am a pygame hobbyist too, so if you will have anything to release in the future, I could offer my page to do it (beside pygame.org of course): http://sites.google.com/site/sipygames/

Answer (score 0):

I usually recommend the [Line By Line Chimp](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/chimp/ChimpLineByLine.html) tutorial since Ive found it to cover the most parts in the shortest time.

Answer (score 0):

No one has mentioned this yet as a source of games written in pygame, but check out www.pyweek.org - it's a week-long programming competition featuring games built in python. In many cases they use pygame, though there are other libs such as pyglet and opengl that are used.